# Handling Amazon SES Complaint Notifications with "not-spam" Complaint Feedback Type

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, feedback-loop

## Background

I'm looking for some clarity when processing feedback notifications from Amazon SES.  Very specifically in the following scenario:

1. The "notificationType" is "Complaint"
2. The complaint has a feedback report attached.
3. The "complaintFeedbackType" is "not-spam"

All of the Amazon SES documentation I have read indicates that the correct action upon receiving a Complaint notification is to prevent any future sending to the recipient in question but doesn't specifically address this scenario.

RFC 6430 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6430) describes this feedback type as follows:

> Feedback Type Name:  not-spam
>
> Description: Indicates that the entity providing the report does not consider the message to be spam.  This may be used to correct a message that was incorrectly tagged or categorized as spam.

It also states the following:

> The feedback types "abuse" and "not-spam" can be taken as opposites.

## Thoughts

It feels as though preventing future sending to this recipient is the wrong action, as the recipient (if i'm interpreting "entity" correctly) has specifically identified that this is not spam.

## Questions

1. Is it possible for multiple complaint notifications to be received for a single E-Mail (assuming a single recipient), E.g. an "abuse" complaint followed by a "not-spam" complaint?
2. If the answer to the previous question is yes, should a "not-spam" complaint reverse any previous action taken for an "abuse" complaint?
3. Overall, what is the correct way to handle a "not-spam" complaint?

Comment: It's been a few years… How did you end up handling these and how often do they occur? The number of complaints is taken into account by Amazon to estimate the quality of the customer's mailing and if `not-spam` counts towards it that might be a problem.